# using date in $match not working in my javascript code, (node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to make a query in my javascript code, when I try to execute the query it in robo3t it works, but when I try it in my angular code, it doesn't can you please help me?

Here is the code in robo3t.

```
db.getCollection('interviews').aggregate({
          $match: {
            status: {
              $ne: 'Callback'
            },
            dateInserted: {
              $gte: ISODate("2019-02-07 00:00:00"),
                $lte: ISODate("2019-02-08 00:00:00")
            },
            'insertedBy.adminId': '5c353f840fe0fd000440df01'
          }
        },          
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
               insertedBy: '$insertedBy.email'
            },
              timeExported: {$first: '$dateInserted'},
            total: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          },
        },            
        {
          $limit: 100
        }
)
```

and the result shows:
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTDB2.png)

Now here is my code in angular

```
 query = [{
        $match: {
          status: {
            $ne: 'Callback'
          },
          dateInserted: {
            $gte: new Date("2019-02-07 00:00:00").toISOString(),
            $lte: new Date("2019-02-08 00:00:00").toISOString()
          },
          'insertedBy.adminId': localStorage.getItem('_lgu_')
        }
      },

      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
             insertedBy: '$insertedBy.email'
          },
            timeExported: {$last: '$dateInserted'},
          total: {
            $sum: 1
          }
        },
      },

      {
        $limit: 100
        },
      {
        $sort: {
          total: 1
        }
      }
      ]
```

Now when I try the query in angular, it doesn't give any result and when I remove the date condition:

```
 dateInserted: {
                $gte: new Date("2019-02-07 00:00:00").toISOString(),
                $lte: new Date("2019-02-08 00:00:00").toISOString()
              },
```

It will give a result but not what I am expecting.

Comment: try this, 

        dateInserted: {
                $gte: {$toDate: "2019-02-07 00:00:00"},
                $lte: {$toDate: "2019-02-08 00:00:00"}
              }

Comment: Ok @Visrozar, I hope it works. :)

Comment: Hi @Visrozar, I tried the code, unfortunately, it did not work.